# Cascading lists drop-downs in SharePoint Designer (no server-side code) without postback

Tags: sharepoint-designer, client-object-model, dropdown, postback, cascading

I've created cascading drop downs populated from SharePoint lists, by [following this post](http://larslynch.blogspot.co.il/2010/01/no-code-cascading-lists-in-sharepoint.html) by Lars in SharePoint designer without using code, it works fine, my issue is that the secondary drop down only populates if the main drop down causes auto-post-back, is there any way to make the secondary drop down populate without causing post back and without using server-side code?

Answer (score 1):

I don't get it. Cascading means exactly this: one depends on another. In your case, the secondary dropdown can only be populated once a selection on the first dropdown has been made and sent back to the server with autopostback=true. 
The query of the secondary dropdown datasource needs to receive the value of the parameter from the first dropdown selection.
How could the secondary dropdown populate without it?

The only thing that you could try is to set the DefaultValue property for the datasource ControlParameter.

Comment: Thanks for your'e reply, the thing is i'm using the main drop down as a control parameter in my data view's select command, and once I select it's value instead of causing post-back i'm calling the data view's manual refresh function which causes only partial post back - __doPostBack('ctl00$m$g_41f15437_f263_46cb_9aa1_22c7c42f7f59$ctl01','__cancel'); now i need to add another filter using this secondary cascading dropdown, and i want it to populate without postback for the entire page, if that's possible.

Comment: show us some code so that we can better undestand

Comment: There is only some client side code that on the main drop down change calls the data view's "_dopostback" function, anyways I've changed my solution so that now my secondary drop down is populated via SPservices whenever the main drop down select value is changed, with a the SPservices caml query containing it's value, it works fine, thank's again for replying!

Answer (score -1):

I have a simple solution without any JavaScript code: [Cascading Drop Down Lists in SharePoint](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/cascading-drop-down-lists-in-sharepoint). Let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: You're likely not a Stack Overflow user... almost ALL answers include links, because otherwise it would be impossible/impractical to include the full explanation in an answer. Anyway, I have no interest in this, so you are free to delete all of my answers if you like, and have a nice life.