# Cascading Dropdown

Tags: 2013, lookup-column, cascading

I am new to SharePoint 2013. What I need to figure out is based on the following situation. I have several school districts with multiple schools within the school district. I would like to create a cascading dropdown that 1st lists the districts and then will automatically populate a list of schools within a particular district when the district is selected. Can someone tell me if this is possible and if so what steps do I take to achieve it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest putting the districts and their schools in a Term Set and use a Managed Metadata column.

Comment: Is SharePoint Server required to create the Term Set?

Answer (score 2):

Paul's solution - managed metadata - works well if your list is stable and if you do not need to attach additional properties to each item (e.g. school address, contact, etc.).

An alternate option is to use two SharePoint lists:

- one for the districts
- one for the schools, with a lookup column that points to the districts list

Then you can create lists that have two lookup columns (pointing to districts and schools respectively), and use client side code to build the cascading behavior. This might sound complicated, but this is actually the most common way in such situations. Coding the cascading relationship is not trivial, but you can rely on existing solutions, for example:

- [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com) (author: Marc Anderson)
- [SPELL Cascading Selects](http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2014/02/05/get-spell-cascading-selects-1-1-from-my-office-365-site/) (disclaimer: I am the author)

InfoPath also offers the option to create cascading selections, however be warned that [it is being phased out](http://blogs.office.com/2014/01/31/update-on-infopath-and-sharepoint-forms/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SPServices Cascaded Dropdown](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns) functionality

Or you can modify list forms via InfoPath and achieve cascaded dropdowns, as shown in the following post:
[How to create cascading dropdowns in InfoPath](http://www.spums.be/?p=241)
[[The example relates to SharePoint 2010, but its the same for SharePoint 2013.]]

I hope you already know about Lookup columns, and know that Schools list will contain a Lookup column for District list.

Answer (score -1):

You can by SPServices... Please visit the following link for full tutorial http://sharepointkids.blogspot.in/2014/04/two-level-cascading-drop-down-in.html

Comment: Single line reply, broken link.

Answer (score -1):

I have a simple solution without any JavaScript code: [Cascading Drop Down Lists in SharePoint](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/cascading-drop-down-lists-in-sharepoint). Let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multipel questions, Ricardo. Ref: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/116310/6382

Comment: Really? And why not, may I ask? Is the answer correct on all the places or is it wrong?

Comment: Further this is a link only answer, which would be unuseful if the link breaks in the future. Editing the answer and provide the code needed would greatly improve this answer. However, the answer may or may not be technically wrong, it's just not visible here. Please try to specify your answer...